# Extract a list of categorical names based on unique levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm practising my python skills by solving online exercises. I would like some help with this question because i have never heard of levels in python (i know they are available in R).

> Complete the function to extract a list of categorical feature names
> from a dataframe using a threshold to infer categorical variables
> based on the number of unique levels. Exclude the target variable and
> sort the resulting list.

```
import pandas as pd

def extract_categorical_features(df, n_levels, target):
    
    # Write your code here...
    solution = None
    return solution

# Click 'Run' to execute test case
test_case = extract_categorical_features(churn_df, 6, 'Churn')
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried? In pandas, there's some documentation about categories https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what they are asking:

```
cat_feats = []
[cat_feats.append(col) for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique()) <= n_levels]
return sorted(cat_feats)
```

Comment: One needs to *exclude the `target` variable*, "Churn" in this case. Hence, ```df.drop(columns=[target], inplace=True)``` needs to be added just before of after ```cat_feats=[]```